# How can I create a "mesh" dropper?

Tags: lua, mesh, roblox

Could someone help me change this script into a "mesh" dropper?

```
wait(2)
workspace:WaitForChild("PartStorage")

while true do
    wait(1.5) -- How long in between drops
    local part = Instance.new("Part",workspace.PartStorage)
    part.BrickColor=script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DropColor.Value
    part.Material=script.Parent.Parent.Parent.MaterialValue.Value
    local cash = Instance.new("IntValue",part)
    cash.Name = "Cash"
    cash.Value = 5 -- How much the drops are worth
    part.CFrame = script.Parent.Drop.CFrame - Vector3.new(0,1.4,0)
    part.FormFactor = "Custom"
    part.Size=Vector3.new(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) -- Size of the drops
    part.TopSurface = "Smooth"
    part.BottomSurface = "Smooth"
    game.Debris:AddItem(part,20) -- How long until the drops expire
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, there's a website specifically for Roblox questions: scriptinghelpers.org. I suggest you use it in the future.

Now that that is out of the way...

It's not very hard to add a mesh to any part. You just have to know what kind of mesh you want, what you want its properties to be, and if applicable, the texture you'll use.

Since meshes are an instance, I'd suggest creating a new mesh instance as a child of your part, and giving it the properties you want. This can be accomplished rather easily with the code below.

```
local mesh = Instance.new("SpecialMesh", part) -- Create the mesh as a child of 'part'
mesh.MeshType = Enum.MeshType.Sphere -- Sets the mesh's MeshType. If you'd like a mesh type other than a sphere, use the corrosponding MeshType Enum, http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Enum/MeshType

mesh.Scale = Vector3.new(1.2,1.2,1.2) -- this will set scale to 1.2 on all axis

mesh.MeshID = nil -- If you're using a FileMesh, replace nil with the mesh ID, otherwise, you can just remove this line
```

There are also other properties, such as Offset, TextureID, and VertexColor, which you can read more about on [the official wiki page for the SpecialMesh instance.](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/SpecialMesh)